# a way to allow using function (randomUUID) which has different sources in the server and frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules

I have a nestjs server built with pnpm, as well as a react frontend. Both are written in typescript. I used `randomUUID()` in various places. I am developing a library that I'd like to use both in the server (which ultimately is node) and the frontend (which of course is not)).

I'm trying to figure out how I can tool things such that randomUUID comes from the right place. I've looked up conditional imports (python allows this), but I'm not quite sure how to get it to work. I basically want to be able to say "if this randomUUID is available, use it. otherwise use this other one." Alternately there may be some tooling in pnpm or something else to support this sort of thing? I imagine it has to come up regularly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use try/catch with require:

```
try {
  return require('uuid')
} catch (e) {
  return require('alternate-uuid')
}
```

Similarly, you can await imports:

```
try {
  return await import('uuid')
} catch (e) {
  return await import('alternate-uuid')
}
```

Of course, this is a runtime solution so may not be ideal.